# Jquery additional function not work - number adding side by side

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to get "Radio value" and additionmq function (+).
Numbers are not collected.
Adding side by side.
But I want mathematical operation.
The multiplication is working.

```js
$('input[name="toplama"], input[name="toplama2"]').on('change', function() {
   var value1 = $('input[name=toplama]:checked').val();
   var value2 = $('input[name=toplama2]:checked').val();
   $( "#sonuclar" ).text( value1 + value2 );
});
$(function(){
 var value1 = $('input[name=toplama]:checked').val();
   var value2 = $('input[name=toplama2]:checked').val();
    $( "#sonuclar" ).text( value1 + value2 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toplama">
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama" value="10" checked />
  10 value
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama" value="20" />
  20 value
 </label>
 <br><br><br>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama2" value="10" />
  10 value
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama2" value="20" checked />
  20 value
 </label>
</div>
<div id="sonuclar">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that the values you are extracting from the DOM are string. Which is why your numbers (which are actually strings) are just getting concatenated rather than being mathematically added. You need to parse your string values to integers. You can use `parseInt()` to do that and is shown below,

```js
$('input[name="toplama"], input[name="toplama2"]').on('change', function() {
   var value1 = $('input[name=toplama]:checked').val();
   var value2 = $('input[name=toplama2]:checked').val();
   $( "#sonuclar" ).text( parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) );
});
$(function(){
 var value1 = $('input[name=toplama]:checked').val();
   var value2 = $('input[name=toplama2]:checked').val();
    $( "#sonuclar" ).text( parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toplama">
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama" value="10" checked />
  10 value
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama" value="20" />
  20 value
 </label>
 <br><br><br>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama2" value="10" />
  10 value
 </label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" class="toplama" name="toplama2" value="20" checked />
  20 value
 </label>
</div>
<div id="sonuclar">
 
</div>
```

Comment: @SercanAslan accepting the answer would really appreciated! :)